# Firefox : render issues with transition/animation

Tags: firefox, css-transitions

### EDIT : This issue is deprecated, due to GPU old drivers.

For a few months I get some transitory artifacts on some sites with Win7 + FF : black areas, repeated graphical fragments of the page ...

Today I get those issue with a simple div `transition` [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeum/6kwuhnxb/4/) (click the button to play the transition).

Here are some screenschoots (I have pasted 2 examples on the right) :
[image]

These artifacts appear only during the transition (they disappear when it ends)

It seems that they occur in transparent areas of transformed container element (into the gap) : if I remove the upper div (in the sample) they don't occur (the bounding box is equal to the vertical div).

Sometimes it displays fragments of a previous page render (the black circle in the screenshot).

Also it's not due to fiddle ... here is the result with a local page :
[image]

Is it a known problem ?

---

Conclusion : for me (Win7+FF) the solution consists in applying the transform style to each nested element. If I apply it to the container (eg 'div' or 'svg') those artifacts are displayed into the gaps (within the bbox and between the nested elements).

Comment: just to confirm that I don't see any issues at all with your fiddle on Firefox, running Win 8.1

Comment: Firefox 51.x, everything works as expected & no issue here.